# Conditions for $B$ that make $ADB + (ADB)^T$ positive (semi-)definite

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrices, matrix-analysis

I am trying to find conditions under which this dynamical system converges. At the end of the day, we have something like
$$
0 \leq x^TD_0W_0D_1W_1D_2 \dots W_ND_NCx
$$
With $D_i$ matrices that are all diagonal, square, positive, real matrices, and $W_i$ non-square real matrices. The goal is to constrain $C = f(W_0, \dots, W_N)$ such that that inequality is always true.

I know that if
$$
(D_0W_0D_1W_1D_2 \dots W_ND_NC) + (D_0W_0D_1W_1D_2 \dots W_ND_NC)^T
$$

is positive semi-definite (aka, non-negative eigenvalues) then the inequality of interest will definitely be true, even if $D_0W_0D_1W_1D_2 \dots W_ND_NC$ isn't symmetric.

Ideally the constraints only depend on the $W_i$ - I've considered
$$
C = (W_0W_1\dots W_N)^T
$$ 
EDIT: Which (I think) works, but is a pretty tight class of possible solutions. In trying to find a wider class, I have considered:
$$
sign(C) = sign(W_0W_1\dots W_N)^T
$$

But with no luck. I've also thought maybe something with diagonally dominant $W_0W_1 \dots W_N C$, or the condition that $W_0W_1\dots W_N)^TC$ needs to be PSD, but none of those cases works.

For simplicity, we can look at the case when $N = 1$ which gives rise to

$$ 0 \leq x^TWDCx$$

And condition $C = f(W)$ (in a loose a manner as possible) such that it is always true. It's also possible, if necessary, to constrain the maximum values of $x$ and $D_i$.

I've considered that if $WDC$ were a normal matrix, and had positive eigenvalues, then $WDC + (WDC)^T$ would also have positive eigenvalues (since $WDC$ would commute with it's transpose and the eigenvalues of the sum of commuting matrices are the product of those eigenvalues) -- but that didn't get me anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: For the case $N=1$, you can just take $C=-W$, that will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm so sorry - I had the sign backwards on the  $N = 1$ case, but your answers still works (just now without the negative). In the $N > 1$ cases, I think the same logic still works, only $C = (W_0W_1 \dots W_N)^T$.

But I am hoping for some wider *class* of $C$ that works (since the $C=W^T$ constraint is pretty limiting)

Comment: I am not sure if $C=(W_0W_1\cdots W_N)^T$ is going to work for the case $N>1$, simply because of the presence of $D_i$'s in the expression that you wrote originally. However $C=(D_0W_0D_1W_1\cdots D_NW_N)^T$ will work.